# How to set up WhatAapp cloud webhook on Laravel PHP framework

Tags: php, laravel, api, cloud, whatsapp

I have been trying to set up WhatsApp cloud API on my Laravel MVC project. I'm stuck trying to set up webhook to receive WhatsApp notifications when someone sends a message. The below is my code and it is not simply working giving server error or 405 method not allowed error, in the WhatsApp cloud api side it does not pass the validation point.

API

```
Route::GET('/webhook' , 'admin\InventoryInvoiceController@webhook')->name('webhook');
```

Controller

```
public function webhook() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="GET"){
        echo $_GET['hub_challenge']; //respond back hub_callenge key
        http_response_code(200);
    }else{
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        error_log(json_encode($data)); //print inbound message     
    }
    
}
```

I have added this route to the exception so it's run with the need for CSRF validation. Error received on the Whatsapp API Cloud side:

> The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify
> the provided information or try again later.

What can I try next?

Comment: It requires to set up both the methods API, one is for GET, and the second is for POST, see [the sample app in JS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints).

Comment: It says there that we need only the get method for verification purposes. I don't know why it's verified. I haven't implemented yet how to process data just for the verificaiton it's stuck which the get method is needed only. // Accepts GET requests at the /webhook endpoint. You need this URL to setup webhook initially.
// info on verification request payload: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#verification-requests

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that I had not added my route to the CSRF exception which would invalidate the request send by Whatsapp cloud api. Make sure to do that before testing! Below is the code:

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {
$mode = $request->hub_mode;
$challenge = $request->hub_challenge;
$token = $request->hub_verify_token;
echo $challenge;
}

public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth:admin', 
        ['except' => ['webhook', 'webhookpost']]
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. It also worked for me. But I just added my endpoint to except array in VerifyCsrfToken file

Comment: adding the webhook URL to the except array solved the problem for me. Thank You